# Generating symmetric keys

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-generators

Let's assume that we have to generate huge number of 256-bit symmetric keys. How to do it and how to be sure that it is safe. Perhaps it requires a strong mathematical backend. Don't hesitate to reference me somewhere.

Comment: You may start from the [pseudorandom number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: hmm.. . maybe crypto might be a place to look  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=Generating+symmetric+keys